# Blur not only one action on run in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to action after blur in textfield, in blur first it work only one action, but in blur second and more the action not only one

```
$('.textsynch, .dropsynch').on('blur', function () {
    alert('asdf');
    $(this).parents('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

from the code first action alert 1, second alert 2, and more

Comment: Are you saying that the `blur` event fires more than once after the first time?

Comment: yes, after first time not only once, sorry my english so bad

Comment: It sounds like you are adding the event listeners more than once. In other words, where ever you have the above code, that is getting run twice, and adding the event listeners each time. This will result in the events getting fired multiple times.

Comment: i add in the : $(document).on('click', '.lbledit', function () { //in here });

Comment: That sounds like your problem. Any time someone clicks an element with the class `lbledit`, the handler will get called. So... if I click the `lbledit` element 10 times, it will register this blur event 10 times. That is not good. 

One thing you could do is remove the listeners before adding it. IE: `$('.textsynch, .dropsynch').off('blur')` before your above code is called. Does that make sense? This way it will remove all listeners and only add the new 1 listener. Thus you will be left with only one listener.

Comment: thanks @frosty it's work

Answer (score 0):

if you "submit" action do not refresh your pages, I guess you may submit the form use ajax.And when the ajax is finished,The textfield may be bind event again.So when you trigger the "textfiled blur" third times.It may alert three times.You can try the code like that:

```
$('.textsynch, .dropsynch').on('blur', function () {

    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```